# Resources for long term behavior of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, dynamical-systems

I have the problem where I am trying to minimize the long-term behavior of a sequence of the form
$$\frac{h_{j + 1}/h_j}{f(h_j)},$$ are there any non-elementary techniques or resources for analyzing the growth or decay of this sequence?

Comment: What is $h_j$ and what is $f$? If you can make them whatever you want, then there is no bound on how quickly you can make that sequence diverge to negative infinity.

Comment: I would like $h_j$ to diverge, and for the entire quotient to be summable, and while doing this, make $f$ as large as possible. Also, $h_j$ and $f$ are positive.

Comment: $h_j$ to diverge to negative infinity? The series of quotients to be absolutely convergent, or just convergent?

Comment: $h_j$, and $f$ are both positive, and so the series would converge absolutely for all these cases

Comment: You could let $h_j=j$ and $f(x)=x^2$, and it'll converge. However, there is no limit on how large $f$ can be.

Comment: That would work, but I'm trying to find the best $h_j$ for a given $f(x)$, which could be something more difficult like $f(x) = (ln x)^a$, for which $h_j = e^{j-1} if $a > 1$.

Comment: What is the objective that you're trying to optimize? Are you trying to minimize the series:$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{h_{j+1}/h_j}{f(h_j)}$$